# vue/vuetify modal pattern or best practide design

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In the app I am working on we have many modals, each modal contains a small amount of data, generally 2-3 fields, sometimes checkboxes, lists etc.
The question is how do reset/destroy the component from the inside when it is closed. The reason for this would be twofold:
1) Not to have to clear individual data fields on each modal.
2) Watchers on props would be triggered again when the modal is opened a second time (some of the modals are "edit" and therefore are prepopulated, I would rather not manage this data).
Now if the modal was closed from the outside then I could change the key on the component and this would solve the issue, since the modal is closed from inside a component, then I do not know if I can do this (would be great).
How do you setup your modals? What would be clean architecture?

Example code:

```
<parentComp>
  <customChildModal ref="$customChildModal"></customChildModal>
</parentComp>
// customChildModal
<v-dialog v-model="dialogState">
  <v-text-field v-model="name">
   ...
  </v-text-field>
<v-btn @click="dialogState = false">Cancel</v-btn>
<v-btn @click="saveSomething">Save</v-btn>
...
data(){
   return {
     dialogState: false,
    name: ''
    ...
```

Now in some cases I actually have many fields and I need them to clear each time the modal is closed. This needs to cover cases where "Cancel" is clicked, as well as where the user clicks outside the modal or the ESC key which I support.

Answer (score 7):

To create and destroy the component I believe you have to use `v-if`. But unfortunately it not easy with `v-dialog` due to the transition.

The first solution, use `v-dialog` inside parent instead of child:

Parent:

```html
<v-btn @click.stop="dialog = true">Open Dialog</v-btn>

<v-dialog v-model="dialog">
  <!-- transition component help to keep leave transition -->
  <transition :duration="300">
    <Child v-if="dialog"/>
  </transition>
</v-dialog>
```

Child:

```html
<v-btn @click="$parent.dialog = false">Disagree</v-btn>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/3eypgcjw/)

The second solution, use `v-dialog` inside child

Parent:

```html
<v-btn @click.stop="dialog = true">Open Dialog</v-btn>

<Child v-if="dialog" @close="dialog = false"/>
```

Child:

```html
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" @click:outside='close'>
  <v-btn @click="close">Disagree</v-btn>
</v-dialog>
```

```js
{
  mounted() {
    this.dialog = true
  },
  methods: {
    close() {
      this.dialog = false
      setTimeout(() => { // again this help to keep transition
        this.$emit('close')
      }, 300)
    }
  }
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/yeq9ovxk/)

I think both solutions are correct in different point of view. But I prefer the first solution since it has less footprint.

Comment: As it turns out, you are correct that the elements are rerendered and do not show the previous state, but if you bind them to data that data will remain and still needs to be reset.

Comment: Hi @Michael I update my answer. I couldn't find the cleanest way but this is my best solution.

Comment: Nice hack :) But currently Vuetify dialog animation is 300ms, not 150, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8oAk.png or https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/bf15ab75579a225fe6aa20c5555b17509f25cb7b/packages/vuetify/src/styles/utilities/_transition.sass#L4

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a good practice, but you can add the :key="Math.random()" to the compoment and it will reload it each time as the key will change. It works on close/open.

```
<edit-project-dialog :dialog="getDialogStateByKey('edit_project')" :key="Math.random()" />
```