# How to destory foo component when I close `v-dialog`?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have vuetify application, and in the click I open a dialog. inside the dialog I have `Foo` component.

When I close the dialog, the `destroy` event on `Foo` component doesn't fire.

How to trigger `destory` in `Foo` component? can I do it by vuetify way?

```js
const Foo = {
  template: `
    <div>im fooo!!! <v-text-field :value="bar"></v-text-field></div>
  `,
  data () {
    return {
      bar: '',
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    console.log('mounted')
  },
  destroyed() {
    console.log('destroyed');
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  components: {
    Foo  
  },
  methods: {
    open: function() {
      this.dialog = true;
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      dialog: false,
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.8/dist/vuetify.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="text-center">
      <v-dialog
        v-model="dialog"
        width="500"
      >
        <Foo />
      </v-dialog>
      
      <v-btn @click="open" color="red lighten-2" dark>
        Click Me
      </v-btn>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Does mounted fire? Before you open the dialog? I suppose the component already mounts upon opening the page. That would mean that the v-dialog does not use `v-if` internally but more likely `v-show`, meaning the dialogis already added to the dom but not displayed. In that case, I think the easiest solution is to add the conditional rendering manually, by doing `<Foo v-if="dialog" />`

Comment: yes mounted is fired once at the begining. when I close I expect to remove the component from the memory, which is not happened.

Comment: I imagine it’s not destroyed because the parent dialog component isn’t destroyed, it’s just hidden, which means that component (and its children) still exist.

Comment: You can try `<v-dialog v-if="dialog" :value="true" @input="dialog = false">`

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59843415/vue-vuetify-modal-pattern-or-best-practide-design/59845638#59845638

Answer (score 2):

Just add v-if for component...

```js
const Foo = {
  template: `
    <div>im fooo!!! <v-text-field :value="bar"></v-text-field></div>
  `,
  data () {
    return {
      bar: '',
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    console.log('mounted')
  },
  destroyed() {
    console.log('destroyed');
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  components: {
    Foo  
  },
  methods: {
    open: function() {
      this.dialog = true;
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      dialog: false,
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.8/dist/vuetify.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="text-center">
      <v-dialog
        v-model="dialog"
        width="500"
      >
        <Foo v-if="dialog" />
      </v-dialog>
      
      <v-btn @click="open" color="red lighten-2" dark>
        Click Me
      </v-btn>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Warning: while this seemingly works, you'll lose the dialog closing animation because it's going to be immediately destroyed before the animation has a chance to play/finish.

Comment: @MaximMazurok wrap in child component in `v-dialog` with `<transition>`, which helps keep the leave animation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59843415/vue-vuetify-modal-pattern-or-best-practide-design/59845638#59845638

Comment: @yejianfengblue I know, I also edited that answer. And it's still not a good approach as transition time may be changed in the future, so it'll require upkeep.